# Update only one cell in a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I'm writing a Watch Window which gets data from `Serial Port` and shows the variable info/value in a `DataGridView`. I have a `Timer Event` that fires up in every 500ms and updates the **Value** column for each row. The user can select the Data **Type** from a ComboBox and this way which he/she can observe the actual value converted from the row value of the variable.

[image]
When I click the `ComboBox` in the Type column, bring the mouse pointer to a different **Type** than the selected **Type** and then wait a bit (longer than 500ms), the `Timer Event` causes the `Combobox` to automatically brings the selection to the SelectedIndex. I need to move the mouse to another area and get back to the **Type** that I want to choose and select it before the Timer event automatically refresh it.

What I suspect is, I'm just changing one cell(Value) in the `Timer Event` but I guess it refreshes the complete row. So, if I have not clicked to the Type that I want to choose before the `Timer Event` fires, it automatically selects the current SelectedItem. How can I prevent refreshing the ComboBox when I just don't want it to refresh until I click there and choose one of them manually?

Here is my `DataTable` and `DataGridView` bindings:

```
BindingSource SBind = new BindingSource();
DataTable WatchDataTable = new DataTable();

public WatchWindowForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    initializeDataTable();
    initializeConfigPanel();
}

private void initializeDataTable()
{
    /* Create the DataTable with the same column properties */
    WatchDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("varName"));
    WatchDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("varSize"));
    WatchDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("varValue"));
    WatchDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("varAddress"));
    WatchDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("varType"));
    WatchDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("varDelete"));

    /* Bind the DataTable to the DataGridview (varTable_dgv) */
    SBind.DataSource = WatchDataTable;
    varTable_dgv.DataSource = SBind;
}
```

Here is my `Timer Event`:

```
private void WatchTimerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    foreach(DataRow dr in WatchDataTable.Rows)
    {
        /* Search the database using the "Name" cell in the row 
        and find the corresponding local variable  */
        Var_t var = DataBase.LiveVariableDatabase.Find(x => x.name == dr["varName"].ToString());

        /* Get the new value of the variable 
        and write it to the "Value" cell in the DataGridView */
        dr["varValue"] = DataTypes.GetTypedVariable(var);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I realized that when I try to read the current value of the Type ComboBox, it reads the default value. But if I try to read the current value from a **button click**, it reads the current value correctly. Can we assume that there is a difference between accessing the DataTable from a different thread?

Comment: How do you want it to work? There is a way to not update anything in the row through the timer if your are selecting something inside the combobox through the UI, will that do?

Comment: I want it to keep updating the Value cell even if the ComboBox list is open and I don't click any of them. It shouldn't affect the ComboBox if I want to change the Value cell.

Comment: I might use two datatables. Set the timer to refresh the dt not bound to the bindingsource/dgv (day backgroundDataTable). Handle the drop down event using editingcontrolshowing event. And run WatchDataTable.Merge(backgroundDataTable).

Comment: Can you paste your DataGrid xaml please? I tried doing this at my end, the combobox remains opened while the value in the other cell does get updated without closing the combobox.

Comment: Sorry, how do I access to the xaml? I'm a beginner on C#. By the way, my combobox remains opened too, but the mouseover item loses focus when the other cell gets updated. So I need to move the mouse pointer back to the item again.